# windows storm supervisor error quit when storm kill topology

Tags: apache-storm

Storm version: 1.2.2 
Platform: Windows Server 2008

I already have storm cluster on one linux server and one Windows server. This two servers all have deployed nimbus and supervisor services.
I started one topology, then I kill it. I found the supervisor process on the Windows server error quit, the worker process on the Windows server still alive.

It shows that:

> "error: cannot kill pid xxx process, can only terminate this
>   process(use \F option)."

The error msg translate from the following picture:
[error-info-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAr3h.png)

I have no idea with this error, I already use google to search some answers, but nothing found, so I send this message to you. I hope you can help me.

**Updated at 2018/12/24**

I found that the worker will start one topology processs, first kill topology error and then kill worker error when kill supervisor.

I had compile a new one storm-core.jar, and added some detail log when supervisor kill worker, the error detail log as follows:

> org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 128 (Exit value: 128)
>       at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.execCommand(Utils.java:1914) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.sendSignalToProcess(Utils.java:1943) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.killProcessWithSigTerm(Utils.java:1962) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Container.kill(Container.java:166) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Container.kill(Container.java:184) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.killContainerForChangedAssignment(Slot.java:311) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.handleRunning(Slot.java:527) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.stateMachineStep(Slot.java:265) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>       at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:752) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complie a new one storm-core.jar, in "org.apache.storm.utils.Utils::sendSignalToProcess" function, I added some log msg, as follows:

```
public static void sendSignalToProcess(long lpid, int signum) throws IOException {
    String pid = Long.toString(lpid);
    try {
        // add this log
        LOG.info("Added: {}.", signum);
        if (isOnWindows()) {
            // change this condition
            if (signum == SIGKILL || signum == SIGTERM) {
                // change this code
                execCommand("taskkill", "/F", "/T", "/pid", pid);
            } else {
                execCommand("taskkill", "/pid", pid);
            }
        } else {
            execCommand("kill", "-" + signum, pid);
        }
    } catch (ExecuteException e) {
        LOG.info("Error when trying to kill {}. Process is probably already dead.", pid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.info("IOException Error when trying to kill {}.", pid);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I found that supervisor send signal 15(term) to worker when storm kill topology, but supervisor cannot kill the worker when use signal 15, It must use sigal 9(kill) to force kill. So I decide to use the new compiled storm-code.jar on the Windows servers.

I still do not know why the supervisor cannot kill the worker use signal 15 and only use signal 9(namely: taskkill use /F option can kill the worker), but this should be a windows issue, so I close this question.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I have seen this happen once when the worker crashed at the same time as the supervisor was trying to shut it down. This error shouldn't kill the supervisor. As you can see in the code you posted above, the ExecuteException won't kill the supervisor. My supervisor instead died because it was failing to delete a file that was open for reading. Maybe that is also what was happening for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but are you running the Storm processes as administrator? Storm needs to be run as admin on Windows, or you need to set up the user running Storm to be allowed to make symlinks.

There's a bit about running Storm on Windows at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/windows-users-guide.html.

Comment: I run Storm as  administrator, the supervisor on the Windows server cannot kill the worker process when i use storm kill command to stop topology, however, the supervisor itself error quit...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Set up Storm 1.2.2 locally and ran an example topology. I'm using Windows 10 and starting storm by opening Powershell consoles as administrator and starting nimbus/supervisor/ui/zookeeper from them. When I kill the topology, the supervisor shuts down the workers and keeps running.

Comment: Maybe this question only existed in Windows server 2008？

Comment: I try on the Windows 10, the supervisor also error quit, it cannot kill worker. That's so wierd...

Comment: see my updated question, I found some added message, but I still fixed this. Maybe you can give me some advice.